# KrakenJS & Node-Webkit - Sample Project

Tags: node-webkit, kraken.js

I want to package a krakenjs app for node-webkit but i can achieve that especially for the "main" key manifest.

Can someone provide me a basic template based on kraken ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not the best way to proceed. The `file` protocol provides you a better alternative. Read this:

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/about-node.js-server-side-script-in-node-webkit

Comment: Ok so if i want to create firstly a desktop app and then change it for a full web, i'll hace to re-code my core ?